# When should a beginner switch from full-body workouts to a split?

Tags: workout-routines, beginners, workout-types

I'm a beginner lifter and I discovered that full-body workouts are optimal for beginners. Now the question I have, is **when should I consider switching from full-body workouts to a split routine** like the upper-lower body split or push-pull-legs? Thank you

Comment: What are your goals? Lose weight? Increase cardiovascular and endurance? Or strength and hypertrophy? Generally I'd recommend using split at any level but in a few cases full body workouts are more suitable, usually when you have limited time available for the gym.

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching when:

- You stop progressing on the full body program, and you think you can get your gains going again on a split program (Assuming diet and sleep are in check.)
- You stop going to the gym because the program starts to bore you. (Consistency is an important factor in getting results.)
- You train for fun, and you enjoy the split routine more than the full body routine.